# Retaining form values while moving back to parent jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts-1

I have a jsp, say parent.jsp. It has a submit option which calls action class. parent.jsp has list, Drop down, text boxes. It also has one link 'upload file' to add attachments, and submit button as well.User selects/enters values in Dropdown, list box and then clicks on 'upload file'.

Now when user clicks on 'upload file', it opens another small window with browse option. User can select a file on local system using browse button to upload it. uploadFile.jsp has 'ok' option so when I click on 'ok' it takes me to parent.jsp.
Now, this time, I want show list of added files on parent.jsp. Also, I want to populate parent.jsp with the values that user has selected.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you're uploading a file, you have access to the name of the files. You can save the name of the file in a session scoped variable as follows:

```
session.setAttribute("fileNameVar", "nameOfFileUploaded");
```

You can then display this in your parent.jsp as follows(I'm using jstl):

```
<c:out value="${"fileNameVar"}" />
```